# How do you stop a loop in order to enter input?

Tags: java, loops

I have never encountered this problem before, which means I don't even know when or how to research the topic.  I am trying to create a wheel of fortune program but the input is acting odd.  Basically, I have an `if` loop and it will stop for me to enter input when I enter the number 1 to guess a letter of the secret phrase it will stop for me to enter input but when I enter 2 to guess the whole phrase, it will just continue on and loop around again. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WheelOfFortune {

/**
 * B. Stephens
 * CSC-151
 * This program is designed to immerse you in the experience of the television game show.
 * Have fun!
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // declare an array and allocate memory for 26 letters
    String letterBoard1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String letterBoard2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    if(letterBoard1.equalsIgnoreCase(letterBoard2)){

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Wheel of Fortune");

        // declare and initialize random number values
        int [] moneyAmount = {100, 300, 500, 700, 900 , 2000, 3000, 5000, -1000, 0};

        String secretPhrase = "show me the money";
        String guesses = " "; // the user's guesses
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int turn = 1;
        int player1 = 1;
        int player2 = 2;
        int player3 = 3;
        int player1Bank = 0;
        int player2Bank = 0;
        int player3Bank = 0;

        boolean notDone = true;
        while (true) {
                // display available letters
                System.out.print("\nAvailable letters - " + letterBoard1 + "\n");

                System.out.println("\nHere is the puzzle:");

                // print out the board
                notDone = false;
                for (char secretLetter : secretPhrase.toCharArray()){ // iterates over the letters
                    if (guesses.indexOf(secretLetter) == -1) { // not one of the guesses
                        System.out.print('*');
                        notDone = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(secretLetter);
                    }
                }
                if (! notDone ) {break;}

                // get user's guess
                System.out.print("\n\nWould you like to Spin (1) or Guess (2) the puzzle? ");
                int choiceNumber = input.nextInt();
                if (choiceNumber == 1){
                    Random random = new Random();
                    System.out.println("\nYou landed on $" + moneyAmount[random.nextInt(moneyAmount.length)]);
                    if (moneyAmount[random.nextInt(moneyAmount.length)] == 0) {
                        System.out.println("You lose your turn");
                    }
                    if (moneyAmount[random.nextInt(moneyAmount.length)] == 1000){
                        System.out.println("You lose your turn and $1000");
                        if (turn == player1){
                            player1Bank = player1Bank - 1000;
                        }
                        if (turn == player2){
                            player2Bank = player2Bank - 1000;
                        }
                        if (turn == player3){
                            player3Bank = player3Bank - 1000;
                        }
                    }
                    if (moneyAmount[random.nextInt(moneyAmount.length)] != 0 & moneyAmount[random.nextInt(moneyAmount.length)] != -1000) {
                        System.out.print("Select your letter from the available list above: ");
                        String letterGuess = input.nextLine();
                        letterBoard1 = letterBoard1.replace(letterGuess , "");
                        String letter = input.next();
                        guesses += letter;
                    }
                }
                if (choiceNumber == 2){
                    System.out.print("Guess the puzzle: ");
                    String puzzleGuess = input.nextLine();
                    if (puzzleGuess == secretPhrase) {
                        System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the puzzle!");
                    }
                }
                if (choiceNumber != 1 & choiceNumber !=2) {
                    System.out.println("The number you input is not a choice\n");
                }
            } // end while (true)

            System.out.println("\nCongratulations!");

        } // end ignore case

    } // end main

} // end class
```

Sorry about the lengthy code, but it's a detailed program and requires a lot of coding.  I'm not finished yet, so I will still do plenty of more work on it.

The section of code that is giving me trouble is:

```
if (choiceNumber == 2){
    System.out.print("Guess the puzzle: ");
    String puzzleGuess = input.nextLine();
    if (puzzleGuess == secretPhrase) {
         System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the puzzle!")
    }
}
```

I will enter in the number "2" so as to guess the phrase, but all it does is loop around again.  Here is what the console output looks like:

```
Welcome to the Wheel of Fortune

Available letters - ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Here is the puzzle:
_ _ _ _   _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _

Would you like to Spin (1) or Guess (2) the puzzle? 2
Guess the puzzle: 
Available letters - ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Here is the puzzle:
_ _ _ _   _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _

Would you like to Spin (1) or Guess (2) the puzzle?
```

For some reason the spacing of the dashes is a bit messed up, but you get the idea.

All I would like to make the code do is simply allow me to try and input the secret phrase.

Comment: firstly, `if` is not loop method

Comment: Oh, you're right.  It's considered an if-statement, correct?

Answer (score 0):

A common problem. When you call nextInt() the Scanner does not consumer the newline from the stream, so as soon as you call nextLine(), the leftover newline character is immediately picked up as your input, as if you had entered "". When reading input it is better to read in a string and then parse out any numbers you need, as below with Integer.parseInt(String s)

```
 // get user's guess
       System.out.print("\n\nWould you like to Spin (1) or Guess (2) the puzzle? ");
       int choiceNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

EDIT:
You have another place lower in the code where you are capturing an extra input:

```
 if (spinMoney != 0 && spinMoney != -1000) {
    System.out.print("Select your letter from the available list above: ");
    String letterGuess = input.nextLine();
    letterBoard1 = letterBoard1.replace(letterGuess, "");
    // String letter = input.next(); // get rid of this!
    guesses += letterGuess; // use the guess captured above to append
    // also consider using StringBuilder here instead
```

There are still a lot of bugs in your code, including upper/lower case issues between the letter board you show and the secret code (a match on the all caps letter board will never be a match to your secret phrase, try using some toUpperCase() and toLowerCase()), repeatedly calling random.nextInt, a value sign logic error, etc. But you can slowly work them out. Cheers!

```
 int spinMoney = moneyAmount[random.nextInt(moneyAmount.length)]; 
      // determine random money once
      System.out.println("\nYou landed on $" + spinMoney);
      if (spinMoney == 0) {
         System.out.println("You lose your turn");
      }
      if (spinMoney == -1000){ // changed to -1000 for logic error
         System.out.println("You lose your turn and $1000");
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me an error on that line (60) the second time around when I try to spin and just guess a letter (rather than the puzzle).  Is there another way I should try going about it?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I would upvote your post if I had enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this to false inside your last statement where you have solved the puzzle
since your loop works around the boolean value of true / false to stop.

```
notDone = false;
```

Actually you have 2 errors

```
boolean notDone = true;
  while (true) {
  }
```

this loop will never end you wanted to add

```
while(notDone)
```

So first set

```
notDone = false;
while(notDone == false)
```

and in the final IF statement

```
notDone = true;
```